# Check vibration System identifier on iPhone 7 or later

Tags: swift, audiotoolbox, vibration, system-sounds

Can anybody help with check, vibration system sound works on iPhones 7 or later, i what to know vibration happened or not.
I only have 6s.

```
import AudioToolbox

let peek = SystemSoundID(1519)
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(peek)
```

I need this because feedback generator has not completion event, only with AudioToolbox i know when vibration was end

Comment: Yes, it works. Nevertheless, you can use `UIImpactFeedbackGenerator` on devices which support haptic feedback (iPhone 7 and newer (except iPhone Xr))

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can't use UIImpactFeedbackGenerator because it not have completion event.